# manage.py runserver doesn't terminate

Tags: python, django, windows, bash

I am trying to create my first Django project and i've been following a tutorial for the setup [here](https://codingforentrepreneurs.com/projects/start-with-windows/install-django-virtual-environment/) (so far this tutorial has been very helpful)

The only thing i'm doing different is i'm running everything in bash rather than the DOS command prompt (something else i'm new to)

My problem is that nothing happens in bash when i execute `$ python manage.py runserver`

however, if i go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/ the server is running and i get the django welcome page.

But bash just stays frozen with a blank line after the command i executed. Then if i do a keyboard interrupt, i can enter new commands in bash, but then if i go back to http://127.0.0.1:8000 the server isn't running and i get 'webpage not available'.

I'm need to know why i can't execute new commands in bash after i have executed `$ python manage.py runserver`

Comment: Just launch it in another process by adding & at the end of your command. (`python manage.py &`)

Comment: It's not meant to terminate on its own - it's a server.

Comment: So the question is why does your server work when you run it, and why does it not work when you stop it?

Comment: Thanks @Ploutox like i said, i'm new to bash (and linux in general) :)

Comment: Haha, yes the question was phrased wrongly it should have been, why can't i carry on executing new commands in bash after i have run the command to start the server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

when you run `python manage.py runserver` something is happening - there is a web service listening on http://127.0.0.1:8000/

The reason bash appears to be frozen is that the `runserver` is "holding" it.